# How to add nonnumerical requirement in Route wildcard?

Tags: php, symfony

I know that digit requirement can be added like that:

```
/**
* @Route("/{id}", name = "name", requirements={"page"="\d+"})
*/
```

Which symbol stands for nonnumerical characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capital letter is usually the inverse in regex.

`\D` stands for any non-digit.